# Hamiltonian constraint in spherical Friedmann cosmology

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I'm taking a GR course, in which the instructor discussed the 'Hamiltonian constraint' of spherical Friedmann cosmology action. I'm not quite clear about the definition of 'Hamiltonian constraint' here. I searched internet but cannot find a satisfying answer. Could anybody help me a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamiltonian constraint comes from but one component of Einstein's equations.

$$\underline G(a) = 8 \pi \underline T(a)$$

The Einstein tensor $\underline G(a)$ deals with the metric and its derivatives--terms involving curvature.  The stress-energy tensor $\underline T(a)$ describes the matter and energy in a point of space.  This equation relating the two contains the great physical content of Einstein's theory--it *is* the relationship between matter/energy and spacetime curvature.

The Hamiltonian constraint comes from looking at the time-time component of this equation.  That is

$$\text{Hamiltonian constraint: } \underline G(e_t) \cdot e^t = 8 \pi \underline T(e_t) \cdot e^t$$

This is referred to as a constraint because it involves no time derivatives in the equation--only spatial derivatives are buried or hidden within $\underline G(e_t)$.  It is called Hamiltonian because it is closely related to energy and the overall Hamiltonian formulation of GR.

The Hamiltonian constraint is important because any description of a system at some initial time *must* obey the constraint to be physically possible, and it should do so at all times.  Hence, ensuring that some initial data obeys the constraint is a key consideration when solving Einstein's equations using, for example, numerical simulations.

Answer (score 2):

When you decompose Einstein's equation into a Hamiltonian formalism using the ADM approach, you get four equations to solve:  Two equations of motion in the three-metric of your initial spacelike section, and its extrinsic curvature in the enveloping four-dimensional spacetime.

Additionally, you get two constraint equations, the Hamiltonian constraint:

$16\pi\rho = {}^{3}R - K^{ij}K_{ij} + K^{2}$,

and the momentum constraint:

$8\pi j^{i} = \bar \nabla_{j}\left(K^{ij} - {}^{3}g^{ij}K\right)$

Any more detail than this takes considerable effort.  It is a chapter in Wald, and it took up a whole chapter in my dissertation, which I can point you to on the arxiv if that's what you feel you need.

Comment: A nice answer, but I think the question is more about the physical meaning of the Hamiltonian constraint than its mathematical definition. One perhaps could add: the name 'Hamiltonian constraint' comes about from the fact that one can apply the Hamiltonian equations on this constraint (function,) and derive the equation of motion of its dynamic variables. I hope you agree.

Comment: @John: or alternately, that the Hamiltonian constraint is literally that the Hamiltonian is zero.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! but I think what Muphrid offered is more like what I want to know.